# Tone() not working

Tags: c++, arduino, arduino-uno

I'm very new to Arduino (as in I had to learn it this weekend for a school project) and I'm having trouble getting my piezo speaker to make a sound for an alarm clock. When the sketch runs, everything works just fine. The LED blinks, but the buzzer doesn't sound, which is weird since the LED and buzzer commands are interspersed between each other in the sketch. If someone could help me out with this small issue, that would be greatly appreciated!

I've included just the void loop for reference but have already set:

```
int buzzerPin = 1;
```

And in the `setup()` function:

```
pinMode(buzzerPin, OUTPUT);
```

```cpp
void  loop() {
  //MAKE LCD BLUE
  setBacklight(0, 0, 255);
  digitalClockDisplay(); // time displays on LCD
  for (int k = 0; k < count; k++) {
    if (hour() == h[k] && minute() == m[k] && second() == 00) {
      Serial.println(amount[k]);
      Serial.print(" ");
      Serial.print(med[k]);
      setBacklight(0, 0, 255);
      lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
      lcd.print(amount[k]);
      lcd.print(" ");
      lcd.print(med[k]);
      lcd.print("          ");
      for (int m = 0; m < 1000; m++) {
        setBacklight(0, 0, 255);
        lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
        lcd.print(hour()); //prints real time
        printDigits(minute());
        printDigits(second());
        digitalWrite (led, HIGH);
        tone(buzzerPin, buzzerFrequency);
        delay(buzzerInterval);
        noTone(buzzerPin);
        delay(buzzerInterval);
        tone(buzzerPin, buzzerFrequency);
        delay(buzzerInterval);
        noTone(buzzerPin);
        digitalWrite (led, LOW);
        delay(buzzerInterval);
        // Snooze and Stop
        if (digitalRead(stopButton) == HIGH) {
          digitalWrite(led, LOW); // turn the LED off by making the
          voltage LOW
          Serial.print("Alarm Stopped");
          noTone(buzzerPin);
          setBacklight(0, 255, 0); // set background to green
          delay(5000); // delay for 5 seconds
          break;
        }
        if (digitalRead(snoozeButton) == HIGH) {
          digitalWrite(led, LOW);
          Serial.print("Snooze for 5 seconds");
          noTone(buzzerPin);
          setBacklight(255, 0, 0); // set background to red
          delay(snoozeTime);
        }
      }
    } //if hour and min match
  } // k loop
} // void loop
```

Comment: please flag only to the relevant language, either C or C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to connect `buzzerPin` to a PWM pin (ex: pin 3, 5, 9, 10, 11 on Arduino Uno).

[image: Arduino PWM pins image]

Because the `tone()` function is just support for PWM pins (in your case pin 1 is not a PWM pin).

Comment: The thing is I have an RGB LCD connected to the arduino so all the other pins are used up. And when I use the same pin (pin 1) in other sketches with the LCD it  works :/

Comment: But as I saw on https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/advanced-io/tone/ that function tone()is just support for PWM pins.

Comment: First, a comment: you can use `tone(pin, frequency, duration);` instead of `tone(pin, frequency); delay(buzzerInterval); noTone(buzzerPin);`. Second, pin 1 is Serial's TX. Don't use that.

Comment: Thanks to dda and Nguyen Thanh Binh for their insight about Pin 1 and cleaning up my code! I changed the pin to A0 and it works just fine now

Comment: :) Congratulate